# New Kotlin class in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

As a Kotlin developer, I don't need anymore to create a Java class.
Is there a way to change the order/position in the Intellij Idea Project New pop up so New Kotlin File/Class appears in the first position, above new Java Class?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can customize it under Settings > Menus and Toolbars > Project View Popup Menu > New

Comment: I tried, but it did not work. I don't know if there's a Intellij Idea bug

Comment: I think it's because your project isn't in Project View mode

Comment: It works on Android studio, but not in my Intellij idea version!